# Upload two separate documents to Firebase with same name

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to be able to add two different documents in Firebase that have the same name. Right now if I try to do this, the first document gets just overwritten. The documents have different values. This is how I add at the moment:

```
let batch = db.batch()

// update listCounter
let userRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(userID)
batch.updateData(["wishCounter": counter + 1], forDocument: userRef)

// save wishlist with properties
let wishRef = db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("wishlists").document(wishListName).collection("wünsche").document(wish.name)

batch.setData(["name": wish.name, "link": wish.link, "price": wish.price, "note": wish.note, "wishlistIDX": selectedWishlistIdx, "wishCounter": counter, "imageUrl": ""], forDocument: wishRef)
batch.commit { (error) in
    if let error = error {
        Utilities.showErrorPopUp(labelContent: "Wunsch konnte nicht gespeichert werden", description: error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

`wishName` should always be created. I dont know if more code is helpful here but let me know if so. Couldn't find anything on this so I am happy with every help!

Comment: *wishName should always be created* - there's nothing in that code that creates a document, field or collection called `wishName`. Can you clarify what you're asking and what you're attempting to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible for two documents to have the same ID in the same collection.  IDs must be unique within a collection.  I suggest rethinking your database model and come up with a way to model your data in such a way that doesn't require duplicate IDs.  Typically, you accept the random IDs created by `addDocument()`, and depend on field values to query for the documents that match.

Comment: thanks for the answer but how would I realize that with a random ID? I just need a  random id instead of `wish.name` but how would I do that correctly? I updated the question btw with more code

Comment: As I said, use addDocument.  It has nothing to do with any variables you might have.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document